# jquery mobile popup not working in loaded html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mobile

So I hope I'm asking this correctly.

I have content from a php file being loaded into an html page.  The php file contains the info for a collapsible set.  The popup does not work for the data sent back from the php file  once i change the html of the popup div.

Is this because the content did not exist when the page was initially loaded?  If this is the case, how do I go about loading this content.  I'm really trying to keep the php off the main html pages if at all possible.  Although I'm starting to realize this may not be possible.  Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Here's my html page (this page is loaded after an initializing page is submitted)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>theClipboard: Count</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../inc/stylez.css"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="countStartedPage">

    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" class="ui-grid-c">
        <div class="ui-block-a">
            <a href="#categoryMenu" data-rel="popup" data-transition="slidedown"
               class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-icon-gear ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-a">category</a>
            <div id="loadCatMenuHere">
                <!--<div id="categoryMenu" data-role="popup" data-theme="b">
                <p>is it working</p>
                </div>-->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-block-b">
            <p>location menu</p>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-block-c">
            <a href="#" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-icon-gear ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-a">Go Back</a>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-block-d">
            <p>validate counts</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="main" id="countPageContent">
        <h3> content goes here</h3>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <p class="centerText">copyright 2016 tosco(rs)2 all rights reserved</p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
<!--
<script src="countJS.js"></script>
-->

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        console.log("page 2 loaded");
        getCategoryMenu();
        function getCategoryMenu() {
            var getCatMenu = $.post('categoryMenu.php');
            getCatMenu.done(function (data) {
                console.log("received cat menu #categoryMenu.html: " + $('#categoryMenu').html());
                $('#loadCatMenuHere').html(data);
                console.log("#category menu data:  " + data);
            });
            getCatMenu.fail(function (data) {
                console.log("failed at getting cat menu:");
            });

        }
    })

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

here's my php file i'm pulling from

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.css"/>


<?php
include("../inc/connect.php");

session_start();

$buildFamMenu = $conn->prepare("select familyName from familyTbl order by familyPriority");
$buildFamMenu->execute();
$buildFamMenu->store_result();
$buildFamMenu->bind_result($family);

$buildCatMenu = $conn->prepare("select categoryID, categoryName from categoryTbl where family = ? order by categoryPriority");
$buildCatMenu->bind_param("s", $family);
$buildCatMenu->execute();
$buildCatMenu->store_result();
$buildCatMenu->bind_result($categoryID, $categoryName);
echo "<div id='categoryMenu' data-role='popup' data-theme='b'>";
echo "<div data-role='collapsibleset'>";

while ($buildFamMenu->fetch()) {
echo "<div data-role='collapsible'>
        <h3>" .$family ."</h3>
        <ul><li>test</li><li>test2</li><li>test3</li></ul>
      </div>";
}

 echo "</div></div>";


?>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You are using PDO, excellent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that this may be due to the document object you're trying to reference not yet being loaded at the time of your reference.

I would wrap the $.post in a protective 'if != undefined' block with an else statement that recalls the function after an interval.

(some pseudo code):

if (myDiv is not undefined) { do stuff } else
 { setInterval(thisSameFunction, 2000); }